# More efficient way to build sum than for loop

Tags: c#

I have two lists with equal size. Both contain numbers. The first list is generated and the second one is static. Since I have many of the generated lists, I want to find out which one is the best. For me the best list is the one which is most equal to the reference. Therefore I calculate the difference at each position and add it up.

Here is the code:

```
/// <summary>
/// Calculates a measure based on that the quality of a match can be evaluated
/// </summary>
/// <param name="Combination"></param>
/// <param name="histDates"></param>
/// <returns>fitting value</returns>
private static decimal getMatchFitting(IList<decimal> combination, IList<MyClass> histDates)
{
    decimal fitting = 0;
    if (combination.Count != histDates.Count)
    {
        return decimal.MaxValue;
    }

    //loop through all values, compare and add up the result
    for (int i = 0; i < combination.Count; i++)
    {
        fitting += Math.Abs(combination[i] - histDates[i].Value);
    }
    return fitting;
}
```

Is there possibly a more elegant but more important and more efficient way to get the desired sum?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If the number of lists to compare is huge, then since you only want the best match, you could use the difference of the 'best sofar' as parameter, and stop comparing once the current list has a bigger difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do the same with LINQ as follows:

```
return histDates.Zip(combination, (x, y) => Math.Abs(x.Value - y)).Sum();
```

This could be considered more elegant, but it cannot be more efficient that what you already have. It can also work with any type of `IEnumerable` (so you don't need specifically an `IList`), but that does not have any practical importance in your situation.

You can also reject a `histDates` as soon as the running sum of differences becomes larger than the smallest sum seen so far if you have this information at hand.

Comment: In regards to using the sums only - isn't he summing the absolute individual difference of each individual record? { 1, 5 } and { 2, 4 } both have 6 as sum but would result in a difference of 2, right?

Answer (score 1):

This is possible without using lists. Instead of filling your two lists you just want to have the sum of each values for a single list, e.g. *IList combination* becomes *int combinationSum*.

Do the same for histDates list.

Then substract those two values. No loop in this case is needed.

Comment: If one list contains 1 and 5, the other contains 2 and 4, they would then be considered equal, right? In his example he's summing the absolute difference of each element.

Comment: He'll need to get as well the number of values of course. An integer to increment at each sum. If the number of elements is the same then you can compute the absolute difference, otherwise return Math.MaxValue

Comment: This approach is not equal since the order matters.

Answer (score 0):

you can do more elegant with LINQ but it will not be more efficient... if you can calculate the sums while adding the items to the list you might get an edge...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I want to garantee any direct improvment of efficiancy as I can't test it right now but this at least looks nicer:

```
if (combination.Count != histDates.Count)
                return decimal.MaxValue;

return combination.Select((t, i) => Math.Abs(t - histDates[i].Value)).Sum();
```