# Finding a good match of two lists of numbers

Tags: c#, algorithm

I got two sets of numbers, with **SET2** having more items in it usually. It's guaranteed that the count of **SET2**  is equal or greater than the count of **SET1**. 
Acutally, since the order matters the input are rather lists than sets.

My goal is to combine (sum up) / reorder the numbers from **SET2** to make it as similar to **SET1** as possible. I define the similarity as the sum of the deviations at every position. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14480336/more-efficient-way-to-build-sum-than-for-loop/14480404#14480404) for the way I calculate the similarity. The smaller the sum, the better.

My first approach was to try all combinations and pick the best one. This only works for quite small sets (esp. the second one). See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14438404/pool-numbers-in-a-set-of-numbers-to-match-the-size-of-another-set/14440778#14440778) and the answer from Rawling. 
Is there a smarter way to get a good combination? I definitely don't need the best one. A good one would be fine as a result. Obviously a sets with empty subsets are nonsense. Extremly unbalanced sets don't seem to be very promising to me. SET1 tends to have about 8 but can have up to 18 entries. SET2 has often a count of more than 10 (up to 35).
The sum of the numbers in the two sets is equal (except for rounding errors).

Here is an example with good and bad results (not all possible ones):

```
SET1 = { 272370, 194560, 233430 }; SET2 = { 53407.13, 100000, 365634.03, 181319.07 }

      272370            |      194560          |        233430 
---------------------------------------------------------------------
     365634.03         |  100000 + 53407.13   |      181319.07       (best match)
     365634.03         |     181319.07        |  100000 + 53407.13   (good)
     365634.03         |      100000          |181319.07 + 53407.13  (ok)
      53407.13          |365634.03 + 100000    |      181319.07       (bad)
      53407.13          |365634.03 + 181319.07 |        100000        (bad)
.                 |365634.03 + 181319.07 | 53407.13 + 100000    (invalid)
53407.13 + 100000 |365634.03 + 181319.07 |                      (invalid)
```

Please let me know if I forgot to describe a premiss or my description is unclear or even faulty. I'm also happy to provide another example.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you looking for optimal answer or for fast heuristic?

Comment: A fast heuristic would be perfect. Especially since an exhaustive calculation is not possible. Thanks for the comment @Ari.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heuristic, which should work quite good:

```
1. list<int> set1, set2;
2. sort(set2) // decreasing, set2[0] would be the greatest value in set2
3. struct set1item = {set1index, value, list<int> chosen}
4. prepare list<set1item> set1items from set1 //(index = index in set1 list, value = set1[index] and chosen = null)
5. put set1items to some priorityqueue pq // ordered by value
6. for each set2item in set2{
7.     item = pq.first()
8.     item.chosen.add(set2item);
9.     item.value -= set2item;
10.    pq.updateFirst(item)
11.}
```

It would work like: iterate through set2 from highest to lowest, get actual highest element from set1, decrease it by element got from set2 and add this element from set2 to element from set1 results.

You must remember to check if all elements from set1 has no empty result.

Example1:
`Set1 = {20, 9, 7, 3}, Set2 = {7, 6, 6, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2}`.

iter1: `fromSet2 = 7`, `Set1 = {20:{}, 9:{}, 7:{}, 3:{}}`, `fromSet1=20`.
Decreasing 20 by 7 and adding 7 to its result. Updated: `Set1 = {13:{7}, 9:{}, 7:{}, 3:{}}`.

iter2: `fromSet2 = 6`, `Set1 = {13:{7}, 9:{}, 7:{}, 3:{}}`, `fromSet1=13`.
Decreasing 13 by 6 and adding 6 to its result. Updated: `Set1 = {7:{7, 6}, 9:{}, 7:{}, 3:{}}`.

iter3: `fromSet2 = 6`, `Set1 = {7:{7, 6}, 9:{}, 7:{}, 3:{}}`, `fromSet1=9`.
Decreasing 9 by 6 and adding 6 to its result. Updated: `Set1 = {7:{7, 6}, 3:{6}, 7:{}, 3:{}}`.

iter4: `fromSet2 = 4`, `Set1 = {7:{7, 6}, 3:{6}, 7:{}, 3:{}}`, `fromSet1=7`.
Decreasing 7 by 4 and adding 4 to its result. Updated: `Set1 = {3:{7, 6, 4}, 3:{6}, 7:{}, 3:{}}`.

iter5: `fromSet2 = 2`, `Set1 = {3:{7, 6, 4}, 3:{6}, 7:{}, 3:{}}`, `fromSet1=7`.
Decreasing 7 by 2 and adding 2 to its result. Updated: `Set1 = {3:{7, 6, 4}, 3:{6}, 5:{2}, 3:{}}`.

...

Comment: So... always put the biggest free box into the bin with the most space left?

Comment: Your solution is well explained and easy to implement @Ari. For another test case it worked very well. I will evaluate it further and give feedback.

Comment: This algorithm works quite well. It actually happens fairly often that a bin stays empty. Thanks that you explicitly mentioned that this may happen. I prevented this situation by only choosing the highest value from set1 if there are more elements from set2 left than there are empty results. If this is not the case I choose the highest value of an empty set.